How can I get the ModalBottomSheet to fill the whole screen with the scrimColor but limit the height of the sheet itself to windowHeight - statusbar?
I am using a ModalBottomSheet from material3 - Version androidx.compose.material3:material3-android:1.2.1
    ModalBottomSheet(
        sheetState = state,
        onDismissRequest = {
        }) {
           Text("Hello World")
        }

First issue was that the scrimColor wasn't displayed behind the statusBar:

I solved it by adding:
windowInsets = BottomSheetDefaults.windowInsets.only(WindowInsetsSides.Bottom)
Now the scrim color ist behind the statusbar. But also the sheet and its DragHandle are behind the statusBar.
scrimColor is now correct:

DragHandle is behind statusbar. Looks better on the screenshot then it is on the device. On the device the camera is in the middle and the dragHandle is not visible:

How can I get the ModalBottomSheet to fill the whole screen with the scrimColor but limit the height of the sheet itself to windowHeight - statusbar?
Is there a topSheetPadding or offset Api that I am missing?
